# Ternary operator in java vs c

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Why does this ternary operator doesn't works over here but where as in c it works perfectly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


        class Pack {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            int i=s.nextInt();
            i%2==0?System.out.println("even"):System.out.println("odd");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it because `System.out.println()` return `void` where as expression expect some value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you can't assign a statement like that in Java. Your ternary would work if you used it like,

```
System.out.println(i%2==0 ? "even" : "odd");
```

Fundamentally, Java isn't C.

**Edit**

You ask in the comments, *where am i assigning anything*?

To quote [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators (The Java Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html),

> Another conditional operator is `?:`, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement (discussed in the Control Flow Statements section of this lesson). This operator is also known as the *ternary operator* because it uses three operands. In the following example, this operator should be read as: **"If `someCondition` is `true`, assign the value of `value1` to `result`. Otherwise, assign the value of `value2` to `result`."**

Further, [Chapter 15. Expressions - Conditional Operator `? :` (JLS-15.25)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) says

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a `void` method.

Comment: I didn't get you,where am i assigning anything?

Comment: @curositykiller Edited. Emphasis added.

Comment: Section 15.25 might be of interest too: "It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method."